# Positive lookahead capturing too much JS

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, replaceall

I am struggling to insert a line break before any dates which occur after "notes:" in a string.
My regex seems to be capturing all text prior to the first date after "notes:"
Any help with the JavaScript very much appreciated.

```
const mystring = 'wed and thurs and notes: are just so interesting 02-03-2019 on a new line please 04-05-2020 on another line please'

mystring.replaceAll(/(?<=notes:).*?(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})/g, function(capture){

return '<br>' + capture; 

}
);
```

my desired output:

```
wed and thrus and notes: are just so interesting <br> 02-03-2019 on a new line please <br> 04-05-2020 on another line please
```

Comment: `mystring.replace(/(?<=notes:.*?)\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/g, '<br>$&')`?

Comment: Would you mind also explaining, how could I capture dates that have either "-" or "/" i.e. 02-03-2002 or 02/03/2002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const mystring = 'wed and thurs and notes: are just so interesting 02-03-2019 on a new line please 04-05-2020 on another line please wed and thurs and notes: are just so interesting 02/03/2019 on a new line please 04/05/2020 on another line please';
console.log(mystring.replace(/(?<=notes:.*?)\b\d{1,2}([-\/])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}\b/g, '<br> $&'));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DnH6Mg/1).

The regex matches

- `(?<=notes:.*?)` - a location in string that is immediately preceded with `notes:` and any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary (omit if you want to match dates glued to letters, digits or underscores)
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `([-\/])` - Group 1: `-` or `/`
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1, `-` or `/`
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary (omit if you want to match dates glued to letters, digits or underscores)

The `$&` construct in the replacement pattern is a backreference to the whole match.